# What is constant_score in term and without

Tags: elasticsearch, dsl

I got the same output for both DSL query below. I am not understanding between constant_score and with out that

What is the difference? Is there any advantage over other?

Below is sample query DSL

```
{
"query" : {
    "constant_score" : {
        "filter" : {
            "term" : {
                "name.keyword": "Anthropology 230"
                
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Second sample query

```
{
  "query": {
    "term" : {
         "name.keyword": "Anthropology 230"
      }
  }
}
```

What is the difference? Is there any advantage over other?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Constant score lets you negate the built-in [scoring mechanisms](https://compose.com/articles/how-scoring-works-in-elasticsearch/)

Now you say, OK I get that but why do I care, why is this even a feature?
Well in the use case you posted, you don't care. it actually just creates  overhead.

So when will you care? One possible scenario is this:

You are using a [Disjunction max query](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-dis-max-query.html) to fetch documents based on multiple queries. now usually you would be bound to the normal score given by elastic. but what if you want a certain query out of those to give a constant -big- boost? constant score gives you the power to do so.

You can find a detailed example for such a case [here](https://www.compose.com/articles/elasticsearch-query-time-strategies-and-techniques-for-relevance-part-ii/).